# How to manually change job specs of a dataset?

Tags: palantir-foundry, palantir-foundry-api

Noticed a new artefact in the Foundry system: Dataset View, and after some testing noticed it can be changed to a regular dataset by deleting its job spec and refering to it as an output in a transformation. The jobspec is then rebuilt during the build and a Dataset View becomes a regular Dataset updated via a repository.

Trying to see if there is a way to reverse the course of actions (i.e. go from Dataset to a Dataset View), tried to manually edit its job spec refering to a fresh Dataset View (i.e. create a new Dataset View and use its job spec as a template, changing the input/output RIDs). There is an <kbd>Edit</kbd> button in the `Job spec` section in Dataset Details, and I can edit the job spec, however saving it produces an error message `Failed to save job spec` (in Foundry), and an `HTTP 403 - Forbidden` response (in browser console). Tried to use Foundry API (both older putJobSpecs and newer putJobSpecs2), however both returned the same `HTTP 403` error.

Clearly, the functionality is there (there is an edit button and I can edit the job spec in the Dataset Details), but it is not fully functional (to me, since I can't save the changes). So, is there a way to edit job specs manually? If so, what are the current requirements to perform such an action?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Job Specs are not editable by users (only services have permissions using putJobSpecs or putJobSpecs2 endpoints). That button should be removed, it's probably a relic of the past or was used for debugging.

Converting a Dataset to a View is not supported at the moment

Comment: Makes sense, I do agree the button should be removed in that case (although I see that `Delete` button also only appears while editing the job spec, and deleting a job spec is obviously an important functionality that should be accessible). Do you know if there are any plans in the future to support converting a Dataset to a View?

Comment: That's not 100% true. JobSpecs of workerType 'magritte-task' are editable by users.